# GNU-make : generates "Circular ....... dependency dropped" messages

Tags: gnu-make, makefile

(Please excuse my English)

I'm using **GNU-make** for compiling ***typescript*** codes. GNU-make is more simple and convenient than other similar tools. My original **Makefile** is below, and it works well.

```
all: test.js request.js server.js

test.js: test.ts
    compiler test.ts

request.js: request.ts
    compiler request.ts

server.js: server.ts
    compiler server.ts

clean :
    del test.js request.js server.js
```

As files to compile are increased, I modified the Makefile like below.

```
TARGETS=test.js request.js server.js

all: $(TARGETS)

.SECONDEXPANSION:

%: $$(basename $$@).ts
    compiler $(basename $@).ts

clean :
    del $(TARGETS)
```

The modified Makefile also works well, but generates these messages.

```
make: Circular test.ts <- test.ts dependency dropped.
make: Circular request.ts <- request.ts dependency dropped.
make: Circular server.ts <- server.ts dependency dropped.
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

How can I remove the "Circular ....... dependency dropped" messages?

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using secondary expansion?  This seems like a trivial usage of standard pattern rules, no need for complicated features:

```
%.js: %.ts
        compiler $<
```

Comment: Oops... At first I tried similar to your method, but that did not work. So I'd tried many other methods. It seems that my first try did not work for other reasons. Thank you.